# распространение программ под лицензией GNU GPL

Tags: лицензирование

когда программа распространяется под лицензией, допустим (с потолка пример 
 лицензия РРС) это выходит что разработчик после релиза программы, обратился в специальную организацию и залицензировал её? или просто написал что распространяю вот так и все!

Comment: да, просто написал

Comment: @Nofate, может быть ответом? :-)

Comment: @Grundy может быть закрыть?

Comment: @Nofate, тоже вариант :-) а с какой формулировкой? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Как применять лицензии GNU со своими программами](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.ru.html)

Вот краткая сводка того, что вам нужно сделать, чтобы выпустить программу под одной из наших лицензий:

- Получить отказ от авторских прав у своего работодателя или учебного заведения.
- Присоединить к каждому файлу соответствующие уведомления об авторских правах. Не забывайте [ясно указывать, какие версии лицензии могут применять пользователи](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/identify-licenses-clearly.ru.html).
- Добавить файл COPYING с копией GNU GPL или GNU AGPL.
- Добавить также файл COPYING.LESSER с копией GNU LGPL, если вы применяете ее.
- Поместить в каждый файл уведомление о лицензии.
- (По желанию) сделать так, чтобы программа отображала уведомление в начале работы.
- (Если применяется AGPL) сделать так, чтобы программа предлагала копии своего исходного текста.

Процедура включает в себя добавление двух элементов в каждый файл исходного текста вашей программы: замечание об авторских правах (например, “Copyright 1999 Терри Джонс”) и заявление о разрешении копирования, в котором сказано, что программа распространяется на условиях Стандартной общественной лицензии GNU (или Меньшей GPL, или GPL Афферо).